# Is there anything wrong with having a helper page for a SE proposal?

Tags: support, area-51

Example:

http://solarchallengeu.org/solar.energy.science.and.economy.se.html

It is not clear during the first of three phases what site proposal visitors are expected to do.  The Area 51 site is somewhat strange for long time users of existing SE sites and mostly opaque to new users.  To drag new members through the many pages necessary to get four basic pieces of information they need to make an initial contribution is counterproductive to proposal growth.

Comment: This seems like it should instead be asked in the area51 discussion site regarding your proposal for which the helper page exists.

Comment: Isn't that saying roughly the same as [the Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)?

Comment: What people do outside of the [se] network isn't typically of too big a concern, as long as that doesn't encourage people to violate the [se] rules or guidelines.

Comment: I looked there first, nothing that touches on this question, and I've learned that silence is not affirmation. Furthermore, the level of experience and breadth of perspectives is MUCH higher here. I'm not sure the name Area 51 was chosen very well, from a marketing association point of view.